# How to deploy a graphql nestjs application in vercel?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, nestjs, vercel

I already find many blog about deploying nestjs into vercel. But my application is graphql nestjs application.

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "src/main.ts",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "src/main.ts",
            "methods": [
                "GET",
                "POST",
                "PUT",
                "DELETE"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But I am getting everytime serverless function has been crashed error.

Can anyone help me about deploying nestjs graphql application into vercel.

Note: I try to deploy it from githun repository by importing and deploying project.